# Is it possible to associate single wireless network card to multiple WiFi Access Points at a time?

Tags: wifi, driver, router, nic, access-point

Is it possible to associate single wireless network interface controller ([WNIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_network_interface_controller)) with multiple Wireless Access Points ([WAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point)) at a time? If not: why?

---

I've never heard about such a feature, so I assume it's technically impossible or fairly difficult and rarely implemented. Is it really that difficult/impossible to implement driver providing such a feature? Is it software or hardware difficulty?

I assume that [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) protocols' specifications doesn't limit us at all because if I attach multiple WNICs to my computer, I can easily connect to multiple APs.

- If it's software difficulty, than what's the actual problem? Does Linux/Windows [kernel](https://www.kernel.org/) or WNIC's drivers limits it? Or maybe system libraries (like [libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) on GNU/Linux systems)?
- If it's hardware difficulty, what actually limits us? Antennas? Using single radio frequency at a time? If yes, than why can't we implement frequency hopping (like [Kismet](https://www.kismetwireless.net/documentation.shtml) does)? Because of lost packets during time spent on other channels? If yes, than can we associate WNIC with multiple routers working on the same channel (I know that channel overlapping [is bad](https://serverfault.com/questions/152920/what-happens-when-wifi-channels-overlap))?

Note: I'm not talking about [dual band routers](http://www.cnet.com/topics/networking/best-networking-devices/). I assume that we consider most common WNIC and AP which both work on [2.4GHz channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels). If I have to put my question into OS context, than I choose GNU/Linux context.

Comment: If you down vote my question, please explain why. It would be helpful for me to clarify my question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The basic technique is that the client tells AP 'A' that it is going to sleep and then talks to AP 'B' while A is buffering frames for it.

Microsoft research worked this out a while ago:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/virtualwifi/

Many low-level drivers support Wi-Fi interface virtualization (e.g. the BRCM wl command has options which support this).

Apple's AirDrop and MultiPeer features for OS X and iOS use a similar technique, but instead of talking to a 2nd AP they talk to a peer device.